# How to add row number to sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating an iPhone application using objective-c. I have sqlite database aDB, and I want to insert some of information to another sqlite questionsTest, also I want to insert row number in one column ordered by QuestionNumber. here is my query.

```
`INSERT INTO questionsTest (QuestionNumber, actualAnwser,rowNumber) 
SELECT QuestionNumber,
       correctAnswer,
       ( Select (select count(*) 
                    from aDB.Questions AS t2 
                    where t2.QuestionNumber <= t1.QuestionNumber
                ) AS rowNumber 
         FROM aDB.Questions t1 
         order by t1.QuestionNumber
       ) From aDB.Questions 
         LIMIT %d OFFSET %d", totalQuestion,QuestionNumber;
```

but the row number all inserting 1, how can I insert row number?
Thank you very much.`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. Here is what I did

```
INSERT INTO questionsTest (QuestionNumber, actualAnwser,rowNumber)
SELECT QuestionNumber, 
correctAnswer,
( select count(*) 
  from (Select * From aDB.Questions LIMIT %d OFFSET %d) AS t2
   where t2.QuestionNumber <= t1.QuestionNumber) AS rowNumber 
From (Select * From aDB.Questions LIMIT %d OFFSET %d) AS t1 ", 
    endQuestionNumber,QuestionNumber,endQuestionNumber,QuestionNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count how many rows there are that have a question number that is smaller than the question number of the row you're inserting.

However, this is not what the query says. It counts how many rows there are that have a question number that is smaller than the question number of the first row in the subquery with `t1`, which is not related at all to the row being inserted.

This was one subquery too much. Just remove it:

```sql
INSERT INTO questionsTest (QuestionNumber, actualAnwser,rowNumber) 
SELECT QuestionNumber,
       correctAnswer,
       ( select count(*) 
         from aDB.Questions AS t2 
         where t2.QuestionNumber <= t1.QuestionNumber
       ) AS rowNumber 
From aDB.Questions AS t1
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

Comment: Thank you. but still not working. for example my `questionNumber` is from  270 to 360(this is every time different), and `rowNumber` also shows from 270 to 360, but I need `rowNumber` is from 1 to 90 . every time should start from 1, and order by `questionNumber`.

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I added picture for desired result. thank you very much. This is just sample. the total row always different and the number always different, but the row number should always start from 1, and order by questionNumber.

Comment: The query in my answer generates the values that you've shown in the example.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I changed picture. I think this pic more understandable. Because the code still not working. I copy the the row not always from first row, and always starting row is different.